# Liferay : A query with Liferay Friendly URL routes xml file

Tags: liferay-6

I am navigating from One jsp to another JSP as shown

view.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<portlet:renderURL var="test">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/sai/edit.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<p><a href="<%= test %>">Go to Edit Page</a></p>
```

edit.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<portlet:renderURL var="test">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/sai/view.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<p><a href="<%= test %>">Go to View Page</a></p>
```

Currently i have this for friendly url routes.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE routes PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Friendly URL Routes 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-friendly-url-routes_6_1_0.dtd">

<routes>
  <route>
    <pattern>/</pattern>
    <ignored-parameter name="p_p_lifecycle" />
    <ignored-parameter name="p_p_state" />
    <ignored-parameter name="p_p_mode" />
</route>
</routes>
```

With this the URL is displaying as shown

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/what-we-do/-/sai/?_sai_WAR_Saiportlet_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fsai%2Fedit.jsp
```

Could you please tell me what should be inside

**Edited Part**

Can i give the values for p_p_lifecycle , p_p_state , p_p_mode in the below way ??

```
<route>
  <pattern>/{jspPageName}</pattern>
  <generated-parameter name="jspPage">/html/sai/{jspPageName}.jsp</generated-parameter>
   <implicit-parameter name="p_p_lifecycle">1</implicit-parameter>
   <implicit-parameter name="p_p_state">Baba</implicit-parameter>
   <implicit-parameter name="p_p_mode">Baba</implicit-parameter>
   </route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
<route>
  <pattern>/{jspPageName}</pattern>
  <generated-parameter name="jspPage">/html/sai/{jspPageName}.jsp</generated-parameter>
  <ignored-parameter name="p_p_lifecycle" />
  <ignored-parameter name="p_p_state" />
  <ignored-parameter name="p_p_mode" />
</route>
```

Then the resulting URL should be something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/what-we-do/-/sai/edit
```

For more examples, see http://www.liferay.com/web/connor.mckay/blog/-/blogs/introducing-friendly-url-routes .

Comment: Works Perfectly , thank you very very much , one more question i have please see the edited part in the question ,

Comment: Good to hear! For the edited part, it sounds like the implicit-parameters will be used by default, but if the URL specifies a different value the whole rule will not apply- eg. if p_p_mode is not Baba but is set to Dede, then the URL will not be a Friendly URL but instead be the long parameter URL. Perhaps you want to try overridden-parameter instead? That sounds like it will use your given value instead of the parameter value at all times.

Comment: Also- that example page suggests that the p_p_* parameters will be hidden automatically: _DefaultFriendlyURLMapper automatically hides all of these, and only displays them if they are set to a value other than the default. For instance, p_p_mode will be hidden if it is set to "normal", but will be shown if set to "maximized". This system makes your URLs much cleaner without breaking functionality._ So you may not even need to put them in at all? I guess just try it out and see what works.

Comment: Thanks tbigby , that was very useful information and thanks once again .